# Why is this JQuery date picker not loading for the first ng-click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui

I have a JQuery UI date picker being loaded through ng-click using the following code:

**Input:**

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker" autocomplete="off" ng-model="selectedDate" 
ng-click="showDatepicker()" placeholder="(Click to select date)">
```

**JS:**

```
$scope.showDatepicker = function() {
    console.log('clicked');

    // Load datepicker
    $("#datepicker").datepicker();
  }
```

However the date picker is not displaying on the first click, only on the second. How can I fix this so that it displays on the first click of the input?

---

**Fiddle:**
https://jsfiddle.net/Lt7aP/5556/

Comment: Use a directive to initialize the datepicker. It needs 2 clicks because the internal event listener in plugin hasn't been initialized before the first click occurs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function LoginController($scope) {
  $scope.onLoad = function(){
   $("#datepicker").datepicker();
  }
  $scope.showDatepicker = function() {
    console.log('clicked');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app ng-controller="LoginController" ng-init='onLoad()'>
  <input type="text" id="datepicker" autocomplete="off" ng-model="selectedDate" ng-change="dateFilter('selectedDate')" ng-click="showDatepicker()" placeholder="(Click to select date)">
</div>
```

Create datepicker instance on initialization.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are initiating the datepicker on click. It should be initiated before you click so it will actually work when you click (or focus)

So add

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker();
```

At the start of your controller and remove the ng-click attribute. It should work that way.

You can validate this by clicking two times on the input field in your fiddle. The second time it will work because it is initiated

Comment: That is correct, but it is unrelated to the question

Comment: No it is not. There are generally accepted best practices for initializing plugins and doing it in controller is not one of them